# Assistant Using C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics, mapping, domain-model

I have an interface which I use to map Entities Objects to Domain Objects

```
public interface IDataEntity<in T1, out T2> where T1 : new() where T2 : new()
{
    T2 Map(T1 obj);
}
```

To implement

```
public class MyEntityObj : IDataEntity<MyEntityObj, MyDomainObj>
{
     //props
     public MyDomainObj Map(MyEntityObj obj){
        // mapping here
        return new MyDomainObj();
     }
}
```

How could I write the interface to allow me to write the implementation like this

```
 public class MyEntity : IDataEntity<MyDomainObj>{
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Only way would be to return `IDataEntity` instead of `T2`, but then you basically lose the strong typing you want from having that second type be generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You will have to write out the full generic argument list.

Comment: ya i try different things but i had no luck. Thanks for the assistance.